# Calculating time difference between rows in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table containing a list of songs that were played with the following columns of interest:

```
id int
name varchar(255)
duration int(11)
created datetime
status varchar(255)
```

The status field is effectively unused, e.g. it's always `new` or something.  What I'd like to do is to query the data and overwrite the 'status' field in the output to 'skipped' if `created + datetime` is different than the `created` time of the song that came next.

Possible? I'm sure I could process this in code and update the status in the table but I'm wondering if it might be achievable without doing that.

here is what I have so far:

```
mysql> select id, duration, created, date_add(created, interval duration second) as projected_end, status from activity order by id desc limit 3;
+---------+----------+---------------------+----------------------------+--------+
| id      | duration | created             | projected_end              | status |
+---------+----------+---------------------+----------------------------+--------+
| 4800884 | 1119     | 2017-09-15 11:06:18 | 2017-09-15 11:24:57.000000 | new    |
| 4800842 | 1004     | 2017-09-15 11:03:36 | 2017-09-15 11:20:20.000000 | new    |
| 4800807 | 1185     | 2017-09-15 10:43:47 | 2017-09-15 11:03:32.000000 | new    |
+---------+----------+---------------------+----------------------------+--------+
    3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

So in this case song id `4800842` was skipped as it should have ended at 11:20 but the next one started at 11:06.

What I'm hoping to be able to do is alter the `status` field in the output based on a comparison of the `projected_end` of the earlier track and the `created` value of the subsequent track.

Any help is appreciated, thank you!

Comment: Show the query you have written

Comment: See: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: You can do like FROM_UNIXTIME(created) and then you can use simple math like (FROM_UNIXTIME(created) - FROM_UNIXTIME(select created from table where id = row.id - 1) wollah, you get the exact seconds between those two.

Comment: @bigbounty well the closest i've gotten is calculating a projected end date using `date_add()` but i can't figure out how to effectively join against the "next" row.  The id field is not incremented by 1 reliably so I can't do the row.id - 1 unfortunately

Comment: @ChristianMoen the rows ids are no always different by 1 unfortunately, but thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: Yes I'm trying to format the output sorry :(

Comment: Sorry everyone and thanks for your patience I didn't realize I could edit the original question :(

Comment: Please re-read the linked answer.

Answer (score 1):

[MySQL just released window functions](http://mysqlserverteam.com/mysql-8-0-2-introducing-window-functions/)!

So you could use `LEAD` to get the *next* row's `created` field, and simply compare it to the current row's `projected_end`.

Eg

```
SELECT *
,LEAD(created) OVER (ORDER BY created) as next_created
,LEAD(created) OVER (ORDER BY created) < projected_end as was_skipped
FROM [your_table]
```